# Error while trying to update flask db model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a simple app using python/flask with mariadb

I am almost finishing my CRUD, however, the update is not working.

The code is:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{db}".format(username = 'root', password = '', server = 'localhost', db = 'baby-tracker')

class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Event: {self.description}"
    
    def __init__(self,description):
        self.description = description

def format_event(event):
    return {
        "description": event.description,
        "id": event.id
        
    }

#Main page
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello mate!'

#Create an event
@app.route('/events', methods=["POST"])
def create_event():
    description = request.get_json('description')
    event = Event(**description)
    db.session.add(event)
    db.session.commit()
    return format_event(event)

#Get all events
@app.route('/events', methods=["GET"])
def get_events():
    events = Event.query.order_by(Event.id.asc()).all()
    event_list = []
    for event in events:
        event_list.append(format_event(event))
    
    return {"events": event_list}

#Get a single event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["GET"])
def get_event(id):
    #Could do this: if request.method == 'GET':
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id).one()
    formatted_event = format_event(event)
    return formatted_event

#Get a single event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_event(id):
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id).one()
    db.session.delete(event)
    db.session.commit()
    return f'Event id {id} deleted'

#Update event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["PUT"])
def update_event(id):
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id)
    description = request.get_json('description')
    event.update(dict(description = description))
    db.session.commit()
    formatted_event = format_event(event)
    return formatted_event

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am getting the following error for the PUT request:

JSON I am sending in the put request using postman:

{
"description": "new test"
}

The error I get:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\estudo_python\projeto_integrado\backend\app.py", line 77, in update_event
    event.update(dict(description = description))
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3300, in update
    execution_options={"synchronize_session": synchronize_session},
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 334, in _execute_on_connection 
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1582, in _execute_clauseelement 
    cache_hit=cache_hit,
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1944, in _execute_context       
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2125, in _handle_dbapi_exception    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1901, in _execute_context       
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 736, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\PC\.virtualenvs\backend-_y8cE5wK\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'description\': "\'new test\'"} WHERE event.id = \'1\'\' at line 1')
[SQL: UPDATE event SET description=%(description)s WHERE event.id = %(id_1)s]
[parameters: {'description': {'description': 'new test'}, 'id_1': '1'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

I was getting I similar error with the POST event, but I solved it unpacking the dictionary with '**' tryed something similar with the PUT but haven´t get a positive result.

The update works now (updated code below), but I´ve got a new error. I do not understand why the **one()** function is not working since the row that was updated is there.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql
from flask_cors import CORS
import json

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
CORS(app)


app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "mysql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{db}".format(username = 'root', password = '', server = 'localhost', db = 'baby-tracker')

class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=True,default=datetime.utcnow)
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Event: {self.description}"
    
    def __init__(self,description):
        self.description = description

def format_event(event):
    return {
        "description": event.description,
        "id": event.id,
        "created_at": event.created_at,
        "updated_at": event.updated_at
        
    }

#Main page
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello mate!'

#Create an event
@app.route('/events', methods=["POST"])
def create_event():
    description = request.get_json('description')
    event = Event(**description)
    db.session.add(event)
    db.session.commit()
    return format_event(event)

#Get all events
@app.route('/events', methods=["GET"])
def get_events():
    events = Event.query.order_by(Event.id.asc()).all()
    event_list = []
    for event in events:
        event_list.append(format_event(event))
    
    return {"events": event_list}

#Get a single event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["GET"])
def get_event(id):
    #Could do this: if request.method == 'GET':
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id).one()
    formatted_event = format_event(event)
    return formatted_event

#Get a single event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_event(id):
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id).one()
    db.session.delete(event)
    db.session.commit()
    return f'Event id {id} deleted'

#Update event
@app.route('/events/<id>', methods=["PUT"])
def update_event(id):
    event = Event.query.filter_by(id=id)
    description = request.get_json('description')['description']
    
    #print(description['description'])
    #print(json.dumps(description))
    event.update(dict(description = description))
    db.session.commit()
    formatted_event = format_event(event.one())
    return formatted_event

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

SqlAlchemy will not convert your structure to a string implicitly. You'll want to `json.dumps()` the value you're storing so it's a string and pass that into your `event.update()`

However, versions of MySQL do support JSON as a data type. If you create your column as JSON, then you can declare it in the SQLAlchemy model as JSON and *then* it will automatically handle the structure without you having to convert it to a JSON document.

Comment: May you give an example of it, please?! The function request.get_json('description') returns a dictionary, not a json.

Comment: You need to convert the dictionary to a string. One of the easiest ways to do that is to use json.dumps(). Or use the text of the response rather than calling get_json()

Comment: I made it work based in what you told me... the update works, but I am getting a new error in format_event function.

Comment: I am going to create a new question for that.